# Using MBProgressHUD With Segue Defined in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, segue, mbprogresshud

I want to use `MBProgressHUD` library for viewing loading panes in my project. Normally I would use this code to show it on the screen:

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

You can see that the `myTask` function should be defined and contains the code that is loading.

But how can I use this `showWhileExecuting` method with `prepareForSegue` event? I am pushing views in my storyboard so no code is involved, I just Ctrl+Drag to target view. I mean I don't have any code to include for a method to use with `selector`.

I tried to define a null method and use it for `MBProgressHUD showWhileExecuting` method `selector` but it didn't work.

I also tried following method to use in `selector`, it worked but it caused crash:

```
- (void)nullTask {
[HUD show:YES];
}
```

So, any suggestions? While using push segues with IB, where should I define the `MBProgressHUD` methods to show it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at the documentation for the `UIViewController` method

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

That's probably the method you want to be working in. (Anytime you use this, you should set the identifier of your segue in IB, so you know you're coming from the right one.) Anyway, this should be defined in the original view controller. From there you should be able to call `[HUD show:YES];`. I haven't tried it, so depending on where you call the methods that are blocking, you may need to play around with where you call show and hide (or whatever the method is to close the HUD).

Good luck!

Comment: I tried it, that's the result: It is showing the indicator after the target view is loaded on the screen. I mean, you wait for a couple of seconds, then the view is loaded, when you navigate back, you see that the loading pane is on the screen.

Comment: Well, you might also try implementing `prepareForSegue` on the original view controller. I guess it gets called in both places. (I didn't know this.)

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It looks like it's only getting called on the original view controller, not on the target that gets pushed. Sorry!

Comment: I edited my answer to say it should be in the original view controller.

Comment: It's all right. I actually making it work with a different way similar to what you say. I define a MBProgressHUD variable in parent view, pass it to child view and set its show property to NO in child's viewDidLoad. But that's  not a solution, that's an alternative way. Because this way, I have to implement MBProgressHUD variable in every child view.